# What is mean by error 'unexpected token' in node.js,and how to remove it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a bot on action on google , but I am getting an error 'unexpected token', how can I remove it,
Unexpected token (12:13) like this , It meant something error is is between line 12 and 13

```
12.if(Work ==== 'do'){
13. if(d.format(date,'ddd')==='Mon' && d.format(date,'hh:mm')==='09:00')
```

Comment: `if(Work ==== 'do'){` has a typo. It should only have *two* or *three* `=`.

Comment: @cwallenpoole generally 3 is preferred.

Comment: @DanielA.White Depends on context. Loose equality has valid use cases, especially if the data comes from an untrustworthy API.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `====` in line **12**. Perhaps you want the comparison operator `==` or `===`

Answer (score 0):

> Unexpected token (12:13) means(generally syntactical error)

Something wrong in your code (13th position(character) in line 12). Your comparison operator has an extra `=` in it.
Make it `==` or `===`.